# How to access session data in a POST request within Sveltekit

Tags: node.js, authentication, session, sveltekit, supabase

Specifically, I wish to insert a record into a Supabase table by an authenticated user.

Retrieving data by an authenticated user works fine:

```
export const load = async ({ params, locals: { supabase, getSession } }) => {
    const session = await getSession()
```

But inserting data through an API endpoint using POST does not work; I presume because the session data is `null`

```
export const POST = async ({ locals: { supabase, getSession } }) => {
    const session = await getSession()
```

In order to send the authenticated user with the request, I wish to access session during a POST request on the api endpoint within Sveltekit.

Why can't POST access session, and how do I rectify this?

For reference, I used this guide as basis for my application:

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-sveltekit

With the Supabase Auth Helpers:
https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/tree/main/packages/sveltekit

The docs suggest that session is available within the API endpoints, and form actions, but both return `null`, even within the same file as the functioning `load` request

Comment: You would need to share more information about how you are making requests to this endpoint.